# How to put spaces intro array

Tags: arrays, c, string, char, strtok

I have strings, that served in array. Then I do this manipulation, like rearranging letters in word. It should be like "I like dogs" -> "I keli gsdo" And then i need to do the opposite, like make this string to "I like dogs again"

It's how I get sentences:

```
do {
        gets_s(sent);
        if (strcmp(sent, STEND) == 0) 
            break;
        mp[k] = _strdup(sent); 
    } while (++k < NMAX);
```

And how i changing letters

```
for (int rech = 0; rech < k; rech++) {
        char *piece;
        piece = strtok(mp[rech], " ");
        while (piece != NULL) { 
            char temp[20];
            char *piece2 = temp;
            
            strcpy(piece2, piece);
            int k = strlen(piece) / 2;
            int i =strlen(piece);
            for (i - 1; i != 0; i--) {
                piece[k - 1] = piece2[i - 1];
                k--;
            }
            k = strlen(piece) / 2;
            for (i = 0;k!=strlen(piece);i++) {
                piece[k] = piece2[i];
                k++;
            }
    
            


            //printf("%s ", piece1);
            printf("%s ", piece);
            piece = strtok(NULL, " "); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

But when I want to get my first sentence again in array mp, i've got "likeldogsdo". And as there is no spaces, I can't get this text again.
How I can put spaces into this string?

Comment: Please post a [mre].  It's helpful to hardcode the input.

Comment: Using `strtok` to find just spaces seems a bit overkill.  If you walked through the string manually, you would have all the information you need about word start / end position, which would also mean length, which would also allow in-place swapping of characters for each of the half-words.  This makes the operation non-destructive and reversible, as opposed to `strtok` which will write NUL bytes into the original string and could be part of the reason you are having problems.

Comment: how to arrange the letters in the odd letters word example `"about"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand how `strtok` actually works.

In C, every string is terminated by a NUL character (`"\0"`), to mark the end of the string. So `"Foo"` is in fact

`{ 'F', 'o', 'o', '\0' }`

in memory. Now what `strtok` does is searching for a token and replacing the token by a NUL byte. So if you call this

```
char str[] = "I like dogs";
strtok(str, " ");
```

the string `str` is changed to

`"I\0like dogs"`

and a pointer to the beginning is returned. If you now read that string, it's just `"I"`. Next time you call `strtok` the string will look like this:

`"I\0like\0dogs"`

and you get a pointer to the `l`, so reading this as a string gets you `"like"`. The third call will just return a pointer to the `d`, as there are no further spaces and thus you get `"dogs"`.

Note how `strtok` changes your initial string, as it replaces the spaces with NUL bytes, and how you never get the spaces themselves back from your `strtok` calls?

I think by now you understand why your code is not working the way you expect it to work, don't you?

A much easier approach would be to not use `strtok` at all. After all finding a space character in a C string is pretty simple:

```
char * str = ...;
size_t nextSep = 0;

while (str[nextSep] && str[nextSep] != ' ') nextSep++;
// When you get here, str[nextSep] is either a space
// or a NUL byte, in which case the end of the string was
// reached before a space was found.
```

Repeat this loop within another loop and without resetting `nextSep` back to zero and you will jump from space to space until you hit the end of the string.